# Schema validation for JSON

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there way to do schema validation on JSON documents, just like the xsd schema validation for XML documents in MarkLogic 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native JSON schema validation in MarkLogic 8, but [`xdmp.jsonNodeValidate()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.jsonValidateNode) is available in MarkLogic 9.

Having said that, there are many JS JSON validation libraries. Therefore, it is not unrealistic to think that you could use a validation library in JavaScript for this task.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've done some encouraging experiments with jsen (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsen), which generates a validation function for a schema. To validate JSON on the server, you execute the validation function in the server-side JavaScript engine.

Comment: Ooh. Do tell more, @ehennum.

Comment: Ummm.  Well.  That's really all there is to it.  1.  Write the JSON schema.  2. Generate the JavaScript validation function.  3. Any time you want to validate a document against that JSON schema, pass the document to the generated JavaScript validation function.  At the time, jsen was compared well on both completeness and performance, but there's a lot of activity in JSON schema validators.